# How to manage Spring Boot properties Map with global default value?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

I'd need to manage in my Springboot application a specific behaviour: I need to be able to activate a feature for some customers only (or disable this feature as well), but having a default global value in case the feature flag is not defined for a given customer.

For example:

```yaml
mycomponent1:
  myfeature1:
    enabled: true
    enabled.customer1: false
```

would mean that feature1 is enabled for all customers but customer1.

What is the correct way to manage this kind of override as, in my property class, I cannot have both fields with the same name:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mycomponent1.myfeature1")
public MyComponent1Properties {

    private Boolean enabled;

    private Map<String, Boolean> enabled;

}
```

I tried to rename my fields the following way to be able to have both fields populated in the class:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mycomponent1.myfeature1")
public MyComponent1Properties {

    private Boolean enabled;

    private Map<String, Boolean> enabledWithId;

    public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabledWithId(Map<String, Boolean> enabled) {
        this.enabledWithId = enabledWithId;
    }

}
```

but this doesn't work because either I have to rename my properties as well (and I don't want it) or the fields are not populated because setter name does not match the properties and then the properties binder cannot populate field.

Could someone advise about the right way to handle such Map values with one global default value ?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice for this is to create a property for, so-called, blacklisted customers:

```
mycomponent1:
  myfeature1:
    enabled: true
    blacklisted: customer1,customer6
```

And in your code: `private List<String> blacklisted;`

Thus, your feature will be enabled for everyone, except blacklisted customers. Just do not forget to check that your customer in this list :)

Hope it will helps you.